# Fixed footer in Bottomsheet Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to add a fixed button at the bottom of compose bottomsheet. The button should be visible at all times in collapsed state and should stay static at the bottom as the user slides up through the sheet.

Sample behavior: https://medium.com/@KaneCheshire/sticky-ui-in-android-bottom-sheet-3d65ea1d20dc

I have tried using a subcompose layout and placed the button by subtracting button height from visible sheet height like so;

```
constraints.maxHeight - sheetState.offset.value - ctaPlaceable.height
```

but with this I cant achieve the desired transition when the sheet is sliding *down* from collapsed to dismissed as the button remain fixed at their position. I want the buttons to slide down when the sheet is being dismissed and remain fixed in their position when the sheet is sliding up.

Can anyone help?